# Connect Oracle database using AD account via OID

Tags: oracle, active-directory

We have configured Oracle Internet Directory. We have integrated OID with AD. We have also registered Oracle database with OID. And we are now trying to configure authentication to the database with AD users.

Any suggestions, what additional steps should be done to connect to the Oracle database using AD accounts.

We have read many documentations about OID but have not found any certain step by step instructions how to configure it.

We are newbies with this product.

Waiting your suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you looking for is an implementation EUS (Enterprise User Security).

As of now, EUS will only work with OID and OUD (Oracle Unified Directory). This is because of it's requirement of the LDAP protocol, which AD can not provide. However, there is a way to configure an OUD Proxy, connected to a Active Directory (ultimately making AD more LDAP compliant), and the implement EUS.

The other option is to synchronize user accounts on AD to users on OID (after you configured OID for EUS with your database). However, this can be troublesome with AD's strict protection with the passwords.

Hope this helps!